# How to efficiently calculate pairwise intersection of nonzero indices in a scipy.csr sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy.sparse.csr matrix **X** which is n x p. For each row in **X** I would like to compute the intersection of the non zero element indices with each row in **X** and store them in a new tensor or maybe even a dictionary. For example, **X** is:

```
X = [
[0., 1.5, 4.7],
[4., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 2.6]
]
```

I would like the output to be

```
intersect = 
[
[[1,2], [], [2]],
[[], [0], []],
[[2], [], [2]]
]
```

intersect[i,j] is an ndarray representing the intersection of the indices of nonzero elements of ith and jth rows of X i.e X[i], X[j].

Currently the way I am doing this is by looping and I would like to vectorize this as it would be much faster and the computations are done in parallel.

```
# current code
n = X.shape[0]
intersection_dict = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        indices = np.intersect1d(X[i].indices, X[j].indices)
        intersection_dict[(i,j)] = indices
```

My n is pretty large so looping over n^2 is very poor. I am just having trouble figuring out a way to vectorize this operation. Does anybody have any ideas on how to tackle this?

**EDIT:**
It was made apparent that I should explain the problem I am trying to solve, so here it is.

I am solving an optimization problem and have an equation 
`W = X diag(theta) X'`. I want to find W in a quick manner as I update the entries of theta till convergence. Further I am updating parameters using pytorch where sparse operations are not as extensive as in scipy.

where:

```
X : n x p sparse data matrix (n documents, p features)
theta : p x 1 parameter vector I want to learn and will be updating
X' : p x n transpose of sparse data matrix

note p >> n
```

I had in mind two methods of solving this quickly

1. Cache sparse outer product of (see [More efficient matrix multiplication with diagonal matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28411/more-efficient-matrix-multiplication-with-diagonal-matrix/28412#28412?newreg=094ca20be8ef48bdbac2639e843af7cd))
2. `W_ij = X_i * theta * X_j` (element wise product of row i of X, theta, and row j of X. And since `X_i, X_j` are sparse I was thinking if I take the intersection of the nonzero indices then I can do a simple dense elementwise product (sparse element wise product not supported in pytorch) of `X_i[intersection indices] * theta[intersection indices] X_j[intersection indices]`

I want to vectorize as much of this computation as possible rather than loop as my n is typically in the thousands and p is 11 million.

I am attempting method 2 over method 1 do to the lack of sparse support in Pytorch. Mainly when updating the entries of theta I would not like to do sparse-dense or sparse-sparse operations. I want to do dense-dense operations.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you explain the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of asking for help implementing something that doesn't appear to be a very good idea at all.

Comment: SInce your `intersect` consists of lists of varying length (0,1,2), I don't have much hope for "vectorized" operations, even with regular numpy arrays.  You can iterate directly on the sparse matrix by using the `indptr` 'row' attribute, though the data and row attributes of a `lil` format might be easier to visualize.

Comment: This is a tf-idf problem, right ? Could you pont to smaller similar problems ? [Google tf-idf optimization sparse python site:stackexchange.com](https://google.com/search?q=tf-idf+optimization+sparse+python+site:stackexchange.com) gets > 100 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimization you're looking at requires storing `p` different `n x n` matrices. If you do want to try it, I'd probably use all the functionality built into sparse matrices in scipy's C extensions.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

arr = sparse.random(100,10000, format="csr", density=0.01)

xxt = arr @ arr.T
p_comps = [arr[:, i] @ arr.T[i, :] for i in range(arr.shape[1])]

def calc_weights(xxt, thetas, p_comps):
    xxt = xxt.copy()
    xxt.data = np.zeros(xxt.data.shape, dtype=xxt.dtype)
    for i, t in enumerate(thetas):
        xxt += (p_comps[i] * t)
    return xxt

W = calc_weights(xxt, np.ones(10000), p_comps)

>>>(xxt.A == W.A).all()
True
```

It's really unlikely that this is going to work well implemented in python. You may have better luck doing this in C, or writing something with nested loops that operates on elements and is amenable to getting JIT compiled with numba.

Comment: Yeah so storing outer products is the typical way to solve this problem the only problem is, that my p is very big and storing a sparse outerproduct cache doesn't work to well for me as pytorch sparse support is not the best. I ended up using a heuristic that is less heavy on computation, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One first easy solution is to notice that the output matrix is symmetrical:

```
n = X.shape[0]
intersection_dict = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n): #note the edit here
        indices = np.intersect1d(X[i].indices, X[j].indices)
        intersection_dict[(i,j)] = indices
```

This will reduce by a bit less than 2X your computation